# No internet access in Ubuntu 16.04 after updating Windows 10

Tags: networking, dual-boot

I have a dual-boot system with Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 on separate hard drives. After installing a Windows 10 update, I can no longer access the internet in Ubuntu, from either the wired connection or Wifi. I'm not sure if the Windows update and problem in Ubuntu are related, but it seems like a strange coincidence if they are not as the problem occurred immediately after the update.

Does anyone know what could have happened and what I could do to resolve it?

I'm not sure what information may be helpful, but I noticed in other similar questions people posting the output of the command `ifconfig`, so here is mine:

```
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:cc:6a:2f:e9:42  
          inet addr:192.168.0.15  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e24f:dfc1:4ca1:3c0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:136 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1106 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:17027 (17.0 KB)  TX bytes:89029 (89.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:26 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:26 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:2613 (2.6 KB)  TX bytes:2613 (2.6 KB)

wlxf4f26d15861e Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:f2:6d:15:86:1e  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you rebooted the router yet?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MichaelBay, I did try rebooting the router when I first noticed the issue. I am able to connect to the internet from Windows and every other device just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seemed to be related to the VPN client for AirVPN.

By opening AirVPN client and connecting to a server, I was able to access the internet again. After closing the program I found my connection worked fine.

I suspect the issue may have been due to using the 'network lock' feature and not closing the program before shutting down the PC.